# Can we increase and decrease the value of number box(in forms ) in html without using the upper and lower spins?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

Help me to find the way of increase and decrease the value of number-box in the forms in html

```
<input type="Button" id='sub1' value="-" />
<input type="number" name="Number-Box1" id="Number-Box1" value="0"/>
<input type="Button" id='Add1' value="+" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#sub1').click( function() {
var counter = $('#Number-Box1').val();
counter--;
$('#Number-Box1').val(counter);
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Add1').click( function() {
var counter = $('#Number-Box1').val();
counter++;
$('#Number-Box1').val(counter);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: please edit your question with more information. provide a minimal code to show your problem,  explain it and try to prodvide an illustration of your desired result

Comment: Please provide a code example

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sub1').click( function() {
          var counter = $('#TextBox1').val();
            counter--;
            $('#TextBox1').val(counter);
          });
        });
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Add1').click( function() {
          var counter = $('#TextBox1').val();
            counter++;
            $('#TextBox1').val(counter);
        });
      });
    </script>

Comment: Please don't paste code in the comments, instead, edit your question and paste all relevant information there. Thanks

Comment: Use your mousewheel inside the element

Comment: Hello @PraveenKumar and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Complete Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var r = document.getElementById('r'),
  inc = document.getElementById('increment'),
  dec = document.getElementById('decrement');


inc.addEventListener('click', function() {
  r.stepUp(1);
}, false);

dec.addEventListener('click', function() {
  r.stepDown(1);
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="r" value="0">

  <div style="margin-top:1em">
    <button type="button" id="increment">+ 1</button>
    <button type="button" id="decrement">- 1</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

```
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="1" />
```

> The stepDown() method decrements the value of the number field by a
>   specified number.

```
document.getElementById("myNumber").stepDown(1); // -1
```

> The stepUp() method increments the value of the number field by a
>   specified number.

```
document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1); +1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="number">
<button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" class="subract"></button>
<input class="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
<button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="add"></button>
</div>
```

use some css to design the buttons to look good. Thank you
works in chrome and safari.